# How to upload presentation file into Google Slides using PHP?

Tags: api, google-api-php-client

How can I upload presentation file (ppt, pptx, pdf) to Google Slides service using PHP.

I didn't find an example in these links:

https://developers.google.com/slides/quickstart/php

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/support

My code:

```php
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile([
    'name' => 'My Presentation',
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.presentation',
    // 'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.document',
]);

$file = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, [
    'data' => file_get_contents(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/Modelo_Slide_Padrao.pptx'),
    // 'mimeType'   => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', // 'application/pdf',
    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
    'fields' => 'id',
]);
printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id);
```

Somebody help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Did'nt work! ;(

Comment: Which one did not worked? pptx?

Comment: Yes. Didn't work with pptx.

Comment: @Morfinismo thank  you. I will test tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot upload a presentation file to Google Slides. What you are required to do is to import the file to Google Drive using a  Google Doc Type. Take a look at the **[reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#importing_to_google_docs_types_wzxhzdk8wzxhzdk9)** which has an example of how to achieve this. Here are the examples of how to achieve what you need.

**PPT to Google Slides Presentation:**

```php
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

// Create a new file
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'PPT Test Presentation',
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.presentation'
));

// Read power point ppt file
$ppt = file_get_contents("SamplePPT.ppt");

// Declare optional parameters
$optParams = array(
    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
    'data' => $ppt,
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint'
);

// Import pptx file as a Google Slide presentation
$createdFile = $service->files->create($file, $optParams);

// Print google slides id
print "File id: " . $createdFile->id;
```

**PPTX to Google Slides Presentation:**

```php
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

// Create a new file
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'PPTX Test Presentation',
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.presentation'
));

// Read Powerpoint pptx file
$pptx = file_get_contents("SamplePPTX.pptx");

// Declare opts params
$optParams = array(
    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
    'data' => $pptx,
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation'
);

// Import pptx file as a Google Slide presentation
$createdFile = $service->files->create($file, $optParams);

// Print google slides id
print "File id: " . $createdFile->id;
```

**PDF to Google Document Doc: (is not possible to Google Slide Presentation)**

```php
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

// Create a new file
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'PDF Test Document',
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'
));

// Read pdf file
$pdf = file_get_contents("SamplePDF.pdf");

// Declare opts params
$optParams = array(
    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
    'data' => $pdf,
    'mimeType' => 'application/pdf'
);

// Import pdf file as a Google Document File
$createdFile = $service->files->create($file, $optParams);

// Print google document id
print "File id: " . $createdFile->id;
```

The only thing that changes in each code snippet is the `mimeType`. For a reference of Mime Types you can [visit here](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/) and for a reference of Google Mime Types you can [visit here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types).

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible convert pdf, ppt, pptx from drive to google slides ?

Comment: The documentation referenced above has a table that explains what format can be converted to Google Slides. From what I can see, only Microsoft Powerpoint, which is ppt and OpenDocument Presentation. I'm not sure about pptx and pretty sure that it is not possible for PDFs.

Comment: Hi @Morfinismo do you get open ppt or pptx in Google Slides by API?

Comment: Hi @Morfinismo may you can help me with this solution? I need publish ppt, pptx in Google Slides and get embed. Let's talk about it?

Comment: thank you. Works fine. Now I will set security credentials. If need help May I call you?

Comment: @ViniciusCâmara Usually I'm pretty busy but I always try to help others like how others have helped me. Glad to know it worked!

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate too much your help. I know, I'm busy too. I'll create another question about credentials.