# How to convert a pptx file to a Google Slide presentation via the API?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-slides-api

I have a pptx file that I want to use as a template for creating new Google Slides presentations.
Is there a way to upload them and convert them via the Drive API or the Slides API?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100147/how-to-upload-presentation-file-into-google-slides-using-php, you can't upload a file using the Slides API, though you can with Drive. Check Morfinismo's answer for how to upload and convert PPT and PPTX files using the Drive API in PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload presentation file into Google Slides using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100147/how-to-upload-presentation-file-into-google-slides-using-php)